# how to fetch mysql join results whose id is 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have this comment table where users can post comment as well as guest, i can fetch users comments like this

```
SELECT `comments`.`user_id`, `comments`.`pubdate`,    `comments`.`comment`,
`comments`.`guest_name`,
`comments`.`id`, 
`users`.`username`, 

FROM (`comments`) 
JOIN `users` ON `comments`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id` 
WHERE `item_id` = '64' AND `section` = 'blog'
```

problem is guest users don't have user id hence thier id goes to db as 0 so it is not displayed, how can i show comments of both users and guest ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT `comments`.`user_id`, `comments`.`pubdate`,    `comments`.`comment`,
        `comments`.`guest_name`,
        `comments`.`id`, 
        `users`.`username`, 

FROM `comments`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `comments`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id` 
WHERE `item_id` = '64' AND `section` = 'blog'
```

If there's no matching `user` for `comments.user_id`, then `users.username` will be NULL.

Answer (score 1):

use a left join :

```
SELECT `comments`.`user_id`, `comments`.`pubdate`,    `comments`.`comment`,
`comments`.`guest_name`,
`comments`.`id`, 
`users`.`username`, 

FROM (`comments`) 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `comments`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id` 
WHERE `item_id` = '64' AND `section` = 'blog'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a LEFT JOIN, not a simple one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `comments`.`user_id`, `comments`.`pubdate`,    `comments`.`comment`,
        `comments`.`guest_name`, `comments`.`id`, `users`.`username`
FROM `comments`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON (`comments`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`) 
WHERE `item_id` = '64' AND `section` = 'blog'
```